# variables not defined when taking them from a class, as well as classes taking to many arguments

Tags: python, class, oop

I am having trouble with my **classes interacting with variables** from other classes, here is the code

```
import string

class dog():
    def paw():
        list1 = ['oranges', 'apples', 'pears']
        print(list1)

class cat(string):
    def whisker(list1):
        list1.insert(0, 'strawberries')
        print(list1)

dog.paw()

cat.whisker(list1)
```

list1 is marked as **"undefined"**, why so? and how can I fix it?

The part where I make the cat class a daughter class of the **string class does not work** when I run it, it will say I have **3 arguments instead of the 2 required**

Comment: So, there's so much wrong here that I think it would be more productive if you just read the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and perhaps any others you might find as well.

Comment: `string` isn't even a class!  I agree with juanpa, you need to take a few steps back.  Start by understanding how variables and functions work before getting into classes and inheritance.

Comment: ok then, thanks?

Comment: But just briefly, your `paw` method has no `self`, argument, which is required, your `cat` class is inheriting from `string` but `string` is a module, and you can't (shouldn't) inherit from modules  (`class cat(string): ...`), your `whisker` method takes no `self` argument. You try to call a method directly on the class, `dog.paw()` wihout instantiating a `dog` object, you are trying to reference a local variable `list1` from `paw` in the global scope, `cat.whisker(list1)` where again, you aren't creating a `cat` instance...

Comment: The problem with `list1` specifically is that it's not defined in the scope where you tried to use it.  *Inside* the function that defines `list1` as a parameter, you can do stuff with `list1`, but the *caller* of the function needs to provide an actual value that will become `list1` inside the function.  You can't use `list1` *outside* the function because it has no meaning there -- you need to define an actual list and make that the argument.

Comment: This is something that you should have a pretty solid understanding of (how function definitions and variables work) *before* you go on to start implementing classes, which add another level of complexity to the whole thing.

Comment: "The part where I make the cat class a daughter class of the string class does not work when I run it, it will say I have 3 arguments instead of the 2 required" there is no `string` class, that is a module. `str` is the string class.. but it doesn't make sense to inherit from `str`. While sometimes inheriting from a built-in type makes sense, it is sort of an advanced use-case.

Comment: so how would I use the `insert()` function in my class?

Comment: oh ok never mind i think i worked it out, thanks for the input!